# Querying database results in the MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose, mean-stack

Where is it best to query database results in the MEAN stack? I've read examples from both Angular and Node/Mongoose but which is best/correct? Should you only send what is needed from the server? Or should you send as much as possible for convenience client end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **Backend(Node)** and **Frontend(Angular 2)** will communicate via rest api and your database and its business logic will reside on server side. You will use **mongoose** here.

You will write endpoints(http web services), each endpoint will serve a specific purpose like **/login** will authenticate user and **/user** would return authenticated user details.
Your **frontend** would consume these web services and render the result in your ui.

You should send only what is necessary from the server at a time.No extra data should be sent.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand where the technologies are located/used. But for example if I have multiple user types and they are displayed on the same page but in multiple locations (i.e. not in one long list), do I make a request to the server for all user types and query them using pipes in Angular? Or do I make a request to the server for each type and display them with Angular? Many thanks.

Comment: if you can display the users using single response then it's the way to go but since you said they will be displayed in multiple  locations it could be cumbersome to parse the results in that case you would be better off using the second approach and also you should keep in mind to hit the backend only when necessary.  by the way could you elaborate a bit more about what is it that you want to achive?

Comment: I plan to build a database of people that could end up containing hundreds of entries. When this database is viewed in Angular, there will be a need to filter these people by status (archived, live, deactivated, etc). However by what you are saying, it sounds like I should call all people with every status from the server, then filter the results in Angular?

Comment: Your client side app will be more responsive if you fetch all the users at once since it requires filtering.

Imagine if you click on a filter and it makes a request to web server this i could think is a bad design, fetching entries all at once and then filtering them on client side would be the way to go.

Comment: Hello @rahulkumar2048. Thanks for checking back. Yep, you have answered the question in your above response: Filter client side. Thank you for your help!